# I've got questions about oaths

Tags: sunni, oaths, mistake

I've got questions about oaths.

I know that if you say oaths in your mind they're not valid but,

1. What happens if you hum the oath whether your lips are closed or not?
2. Also what if you're saying an oath in your mind but your mouth is open? (And you're not sure if you could've said it out loud accidentally or if yk you didn't say it out loud)

Thank you :)

Comment: If you made a plan to not obey the oath you're going to do a sin. .إنَّمَا الأَعْمَالُ بِالنِّيَّاتِ

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid so is it valid or not?

Comment: No it is not valid at all. Purely depend on your Niyat.

Answer (score 0):

This question is nonsense, if you do a oath you do it within your heart. If not, then just keep quiet. Therefore, You will get punished, and you have done a sin if you do not complete your oaths.

Comment: So are they valid or not? 